# Can feature engineering be replaced by metaparameter selection in Random Forests?

Tags: modeling, random-forest, accuracy

Random forests model perform at the level of each tree a partitioning of space with is aligned with feature space.

Does this mean that there are cases where performing feature engineering (e.g. performing dimensionality reduction aligning better features or applying a non-linear transformation to the input features), we can improve the results of a rf model?

Or can we suppose that, if we are in such a case where we managed to improve performance using feature engineering, since any preprocessing would just modify the shape of the boundary and every boundary can be approximated with a sequence of  boundaries aligned to the input features, with the appropriate choice of metaparameters we can always perform as well as the preprocessed model, without preprocessing ?

I cannot find a conclusive answer to this question in previous questions on CrossValidated.

ps: I am not interested in the computational time here but I consider fixed the dimension of the dataset.

Comment: Are you asking, in other words, "Is there an improvement to model performance (increased accuracy, decreased variance, etc.) that preprocessing can bring to a random forest model that hyper-parameter tuning cannot?"

Comment: Yes exactly, thanks for helping in clarifying my question.

Comment: You're welcome. It's what moderators are for.